# EXCEL VBA: match part of a string

Tags: string, vba, excel, match

i'm working on a Excel VBA Macro that can match the same entries in column V with the entries in column Y. Everything works fine but there some entries that just match a part of the other entry.
Example:

```
Column V:            Column Y:
Word                 Excel
Word, Excel 
Excel
```

Now for this example it will only mark the last entry, but it should also mark the secound entry. 
Here's the code that i actually have now:

```
Sub MatchAndColor()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheetName As String

sheetName = "MAIN" 'Name of the Sheet
lastRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowB = Sheets(sheetName).Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = 2 To lastRow 'Loop through all rows
    For lrowb = 2 To lastRowB 'Loop through all rows
        If Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrow, "V") Like Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrowb, "Y") Then
        Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrow, "V").Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Set Color to Light Blue
       End If
    Next lrowb
Next lrow

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your example is confusing. Your code indicates that it should match lines where values in column V and column Y are identical, but your example shows no such correlation. Can you fix the example so it is more clear what you are trying to do? Use `code` formatting if you have trouble getting it to display properly.

Comment: Or simply give a screenshot of the excel file.

Comment: Just out of the blue, would it work OK, if you simply replace the "Like" with "="?

Comment: I've changed the example, now it should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

Updated answer to match question update, this works with given example.

```
Sub MatchAndColor()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sheetName As String

sheetName = "MAIN" 'Name of the Sheet
lastRow = Sheets(sheetName).Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowB = Sheets(sheetName).Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For lrow = 2 To lastRow 'Loop through all rows
    For lrowb = 2 To lastRowB 'Loop through all rows
        If (Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrow, "V") Like "*" & Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrowb, "Y") & "*") Or (Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrow, "Y") Like "*" & Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrowb, "V") & "*") Then
        Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrow, "V").Interior.ColorIndex = 37 'Set Color to Light Blue
       End If
    Next lrowb
Next lrow

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes i've tried this as well but here it only marks if the cell contains the exact string as the other cell contains. i need something that sais:

Comment: ` If "*"sheetCells"*" Like Sheets(sheetName).Cells(lrowb, "Y") Then`

Comment: OK, it seems the problem is that you compare against the second column as a pattern, and you really want to do it both ways.
You need to add OR condition to check second against first.
Plus you might need to use wildcards.

Comment: If you only need to use the content of Y as a pattern you can remove the second OR part and just add the wildcards to the first part as that will do.